# SHOW COLUMNS FROM in foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to show all fields for each table and assign them to a multilevel array, but I get ' Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object'...

```
$sql_tables = "SHOW TABLES;";
$result = $mysql->query($sql_tables );
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     while($row_tables = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          $alltables_array[] = $row_tables["Tables_in_dbname"];
     }
} 

foreach ($alltables_array as $table) {
    $sql_fields = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM " . $table . ";";
    $result_fields= $mysql->query($sql_fields);
    while($row_fields = $result_fields->fetch_assoc()) { /* ERROR ON THIS LINE */
          $allfields_array[$table ][] = $row_fields['Field'];
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since `$row_tables` yield your current database name:

```
$row_tables["Tables_in_dbname"]; // this is incorrect (unless your current dbname is really dbname)
           // ^ undefined index
```

So just add a dynamic index:

```
$dbname = 'test';
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     while($row_tables = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          $alltables_array[] = $row_tables['Tables_in_' . $dbname];
     }
}
```

I'd suggest use `->fetch_row()` instead:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     while($row_tables = $result->fetch_row()) {
          $alltables_array[] = $row_tables[0];
     }
}
```

Then point to index zero. No need to add a dynamic variable in the associative index.

Sidenote: Can be a band-aid solution:

```
$alltables_array[] = $row_tables[key($row_tables)]; // not good though, it'll invoke key() every iteration.
```

Comment: sidenote: the `;` semi-colon in unneeded in the query statements

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry, I probably was not very precise, I get the error at the  `while($row_fields = $result_fields... line`. I'll edit the question. ...I'm try to build a search everywhere in the database function...

Comment: @codeispoetry yes i've tested the code bug, the error is lined up chained, the origin is the wrong fetching of the tables, fetch the correct tables, the columns will fetch correctly right in

Comment: I'm keeping reading your answer, but I'm struggling to understand why $table generates the error... :o !!!

Comment: @codeispoetry `$row_tables` inside the while loop yields `Array ( [Tables_in_<thie database name>] )`. this value should be dynamic, but yours is hardcoded instead, thus the error

Comment: Can't make it work. I did try the $dbname mmm... but I'm querying only one db: dbname: all tables from the db named 'dbname'. Sorry... I don't want to take advantage of your time...

Comment: @codeispoetry you can try the alternative, so that you'll have no trouble using any database name, use `->fetch_row`, then just point to `$row_tables[0]`, its already above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120063/discussion-between-codeispoetry-and-ghost).